# How to call upon a color transform in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, transform

If I use colortransform to set a color to an object is there any way I can call on that color through the parent?

for example

```
var color1 = new ColorTransform(); color1.color = 0xFF0000;
thing1.transform.colorTransform = color1;
```

If I want to call upon that color assigned to thing1 is there any way to do that?

Some things I have tried

```
trace(thing1.color);
trace(thing1.colorTransform);
trace(thing1.transform);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Communityi dont know how i could be anymore clear

Comment: I added an "actionscript-3" tag to your question. I didn't realize "AS3" as a programming language at first - although i used to program in it a lot. It's not as commonly known any more, I think, so it's good to spell out its full name for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative that you can call upon that may actually solve most desired functionality.

if you take the object and attach .transform.colorTransform to the end you can call upon any of the 8 values set to that object by the color transform function

```
trace(thing1.transform.colorTransform);
trace(thing1.transform.colorTransform.blueOffset);
```

or call a value to relay it to another variable

```
color2.blueOffset = thing1.transform.colorTransform.blueOffset;
```